# spring data for mongo Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring, mongodb

i use spring data to jpa and mongo.

**dependency**:

spring version is 4.0.2.RELEASE

spring-data-jpa version is 1.4.3.RELEASE

spring-data-mongodb version is 1.2.0.RELEASE

**xml config**:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="develop" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="develop.erp"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" /> 


<mongo:repositories base-package="develop.doc" />
```

**model**:

```
@Document
public class OrderItem extends AbstractDocument {


    enter code here
    @Id
    private BigInteger id;

    private Integer orderNumber;

    public get and set method ...
}

public interface IOrderItemDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<OrderItem, BigInteger> {


    List<OrderItem> findByOrderNumber(Integer number);
}
```

**exception** :

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.getBindableParameters(Parameters.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.assertEitherAllParamAnnotatedOrNone(Parameters.java:262)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.Parameters.<init>(Parameters.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoParameters.<init>(MongoParameters.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryMethod.createParameters(MongoQueryMethod.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryMethod.<init>(QueryMethod.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryMethod.<init>(MongoQueryMethod.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
```

can someone have any idea ?

thanks very much..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had spring-data-solr(2.0.1) and spring-data-jpa(1.9.1) in my project. I noticed SolrQueryLookupStrategy was implementing QueryLookupStrategy interface from spring-data-commons which was transitively taken from spring-data-jpa jar. The problem was new solr was not compatible with old spring-data-jpa - signature of method in QueryLookupStrategy changed and code was not compiled correctly. Bumping spring-data-jpa to 1.10.1 solved the issue. I assume you have a similar problem. Track down where exception is thrown and search for compilation problems in spring jars.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incompatible version of spring-data and db-driver dependency. Please check if the version of db-driver is compatible with the provided spring-data dependency. I was facing the same issue, resolved by bumping the version of 'spring-data'.